# How to know if a member of a class is a method?

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

What's the most pythonic way to know if a member of a class is a method? Note: I had only the name of the (posssible) method (could be a *class method*, an *instance method* or a *static method*).

Currently I'm comparing the type of the object in the dictionary of the class with `<type 'function'>`:

```
def isMethodOf(methodName,klass):
    return type(klass.__dict__.get(methodName)) == type(lambda x:x)
```

I really don't know if this will work on all the cases.
The `type(lambda x:x)` part is just for getting the type `<type 'function'>`, Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: [`inspect.ismethod`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.ismethod)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Python 2, use [`inspect.ismethod()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.ismethod):

```
return inspect.ismethod(getattr(klass, methodName))
```

For Python 3, unbound methods are gone, and you'd use [`inspect.isfunction()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isfunction) instead.

You can also use the [`types.MethodType` type object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.MethodType) to test against:

```
import types

isinstance(getattr(klass, methodName), types.MethodType)
```

Both tests work for `@classmethod` methods and regular methods. *By design* these tests fail for `@staticmethod` methods; those are just functions that resist binding (`cls.staticmethod.__get__(instance, cls)` returns the function itself). You can test for functions with [`inspect.isfunction()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.isfunction), or use `isinstance(obj, (types.MethodType, types.FunctionType))` to catch all 3 in one test.

If all you wanted is to test if something is *callable*, you could use the [`callable()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#callable). It'll work even if the object is an instance with a `__call__` method:

```
>>> class MyCallable(object):
...     def __call__(self):
...         return "Hello World!"
... 
>>> mc = MyCallable()
>>> callable(mc)
True
>>> mc()
'Hello World!'
```

Using `callable()` works on all 3 method 'types' as well as custom objects such as the above. Note that *classes*, being factories, are callable too.

Comment: Great! but, Which one do you recommend? All will work well in the three cases?

Comment: Just curious - The OP's original code will not throw an error if the method does not exist.  Hence, wouldn't it be better to do `getattr(klass, methodName, None)` to keep this functionality?  Or am I wrong?

Comment: @iCodez: Sure, you can use a default and that'll work. That's not what I am focusing on however, as that is a small detail somewhat orthogonal to the issue at hand.

Comment: If you use `callable()`, remember that *classes are callable.*

Answer (score 3):

Use callable on it.

Example:

```
>>> def func(): pass
>>> callable(func)
>>> True
```